# Can I get the user's IPv6 public address from a lambda function on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ipv6

We have a lambda function on AWS and we are able to get the user's IPv4 by calling `event.requestContext.identity.sourceIp`.

Will that magically give me an IPv6 address if the user has IPv6? or is there a way for me to get the IPv6 address?

Comment: How is your lambda accessed by your users? You can't access lambda from internet, so how it is invoked?

Comment: `sourceIp` is placed there by API Gateway.  API Gateway, at present, is IPv4 only, so you won't see any IPv6 addresses.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question. And yeah we are using api gateway.